# After a particle hits a screen and becomes stuck to it, will we know both position and momentum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, particle-detectors

After a quantum particle hits a detector screen, we learn two things:

1. Its position in all 3 dimensions (it's in the bright spot in the screen)
2. Its momentum in all 3 dimensions (it's stuck in the screen, so it isn't moving: momentum (almost) zero)

Wouldn't this knowledge of both position and momentum at the same time go against Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle?

Or perhaps I have a misunderstanding of how detector screens work?

Comment: Are you aware that $\hbar=1\times10^{-34}\text{ Js}$. How small is your spot on the screen? surely no smaller than an atom ($10^{-10}\text{ m}$).  And how well determined do you think the momentum is?

Comment: You perhaps may know that the momentum is zero (stuck to the screen) _after_ the collision with the screen. But how do you know anything about the momentum _before_ the collision?

Comment: The uncertainty principle is a statement about the distribution of many such measurements. It's not a statement that one can't measure position and momentum at the same time. One can, it just doesn't do much good if we are near the limits set by the uncertainty principle. The major problem here is educational, by the way. What con Neumann meant by "measurement" was the statistical distribution of positions and momenta, not the individual position and momentum measurement that we actually do in the lab.

Comment: @FlatterMann the way I understand the question: once the particle is stuck to the screen, we can measure its momentum and position again and again - as many times as we want. So, if such an ideal screen existed, it would indeed violate the HUP.

Comment: @RogerVadim yes, that's what i meant.

Comment: @RogerVadim A quantum is an amount of energy. Energy can be transferred exactly once. The entire particle ontology is simply a poor mental model that doesn't really work for any purpose as far as I can tell. It certainly does not work for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Or perhaps I have a misunderstanding of how detector screens work?

This is the answer.

You are trying to beat the QM by using a *magical* screen, which detects both position and momentum with infinite precision... and that the particle actually sticks to it. Once we consider real designs, at least one of these assumptions is not true. One can similarly "disprove" relativity by assuming that we can instantaneously measure position of an object (which is what people thought possible before Einstein.)

The classical screen-like device for quantum measurements is the [bubble chamber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_chamber), where a charged particle leaves a trace of finite width and length, indicating non-zero position and momentum uncertainty, in accordance with the uncertainty principle. In more familiar [cathode ray tubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode-ray_tube) or [plasma screens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_display) the size of the spot and the interaction between the electron and the fluorescent material or ionized gas take place over finite distances - they are only small to our eyes. Finally, in a photographic film or the like photons or electrons cause chemical changes, again in substantial distance, and again not fully stopping, but rather entering a bound state with the molecules of the film.

Comment: Small caveat - bubble chambers are a relic of the past, not "the top notch screen like device for quantum measurements." There are several different kinds of detectors in use today, but a silicon vertex detector plays the role most similar to the bubble chamber.

Comment: @AXensen I meant that they do measure on quantum level (unlike cathode ray tubes or plasma screens.) But I changed it to *classical*.

Comment: So the Uncertainty Principle says that it should be impossible to ever build a detector like the one I asked about?

Comment: @JuanPerez Yes, this is a good way to put it.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a detector that reports position and momentum to any precision you like. On the other hand, if you prepare multiple particles identically, your detector will report a distribution of positions and momenta for them. The Uncertainty Principle constrains that distribution.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146275/discussion-on-answer-by-john-doty-after-a-particle-hits-a-screen-and-becomes-stu); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are right - +1 to both. Perhaps this example will clarify it.

A very dim monochromatic plane wave passes through a slit 20 um wide and strikes a fluorescent screen behind it. We see individual flashes of light as one photon strikes one atom. We can determine the position of each flash very well.

In the incoming plane wave, we know the longitudinal component of momentum very well because we know the wavelength very well. We know the transverse component is very close to $0$ because the plane wave is very well directed. We know almost nothing about the position because a highly monochromatic plane wave is very long, and a well directed plane wave must be very wide to avoid diffraction.

Most photons in such a wave will strike the wall containing the slit. A few will pass through.

We know that the transverse position of those photons, though we learn nothing of the longitudinal position. The transverse momentum of those photons is no longer $0$. It is uncertain. We know that the photons will hit the screen in positions outside a geometric shadow. We can predict the pattern that many photons will make with the uncertainty principal. Or equivalently, with classical diffraction. We cannot predict the position of any individual photon.

As we see each flash, we can precisely determine the angle of flight from the slit. Since we still know the wavelength, we know the total momentum. We can precisely determine what the longitudinal and transverse components of momentum were.

If you precisely know the state of a photon, you know how uncertain position and momentum are. You know how well you can predict future measured values. That does not prevent precise determination of what measured values you wind up with.